# Excel Formula: weekly comparison with corresponding week of previous month

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a week on week comparison in Google Sheets.

The nuance is that the **Comparison Week** needs to dynamically populate as the corresponding week of the previous month.

So if the dataset is the first week of May, the **Comparison Week** would be the first week of  April. Likewise, week 2 of May would be compared to week 2 of April, etc.

As an example, if A1 is 5/1/2016 and A2 is 5/7/2016, cells B1 and B2 should populate as 4/3/2016 and 4/9/2016 respectively (where Sunday is the first day of the week).

I've built the following formula which I think gets me about halfway:

=WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),1)+1

This formula returns the week number in the month from a given date. For example, 5/1/2016 returns the value '1' because the date occurs on the first week of the month. 5/8/2016 would return '2', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula below. It looks ugly, but it should work exactly as your example.

> As an example, if A1 is 5/1/2016 and A2 is 5/7/2016, cells B1 and B2
>   should populate as 4/3/2016 and 4/9/2016 respectively (where Sunday is
>   the first day of the week).

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-1,DAY(A1)+IF(WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)+1)=1,8,WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)+1))-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-1,1),1))
```

here is how it works

```
=DATE(
   YEAR(A1),
   MONTH(A1)-1,
```

*return date of previous month with day calculated as follows:*

```
DAY(A1)
```

*start at the current date*

```
+IF(WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)+1)=1,8,WEEKDAY(A1-DAY(A1)+1))
```

*find out what day is the first day of the current month and add its number. Only if it is Sunday (1st day of week) it needs to skip week 0 so it adds 8*

```
-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)-1,1),1)
```

*deduct number representing first day of previous month*

So for example if you have 5/3/2016 it does:
(3rd day of month) + (first day of current month in Sunday, so add 8) - (first day of previous month is Friday, so it deduct 6)

3 + 8 - 6 =5 and this is day of previous month, so result is 4/5/2016